# Alphabetizing a random char list in C#

Tags: c#, linq, list, char, alphabetized

I think I'm going about this the wrong way, I am trying to generate a list of 30 random characters.  Then sort them with LINQ in ascending order.  However I am getting a red squiggle line under the letters variable in my LINQ sort

```
namespace LetterSort
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        //create random list
        List<char> random = new List<char>();
        Random r = new Random();

        public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            char letters;


            //insert random letters           
            for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
            {
                random.Add((char)i);
                letters = (char)((int)'a' + r.Next(0, 26));
                listBox1.Items.Add("Random Letters:" + letters);
            }

            //in ascending
                var asc =
                    from a in letters //error here
                    orderby a ascending
                    select a;

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What does the red squiggly line say?

Answer (score 4):

`random` not `letters`:

```
var asc = from a in random
          orderby a
          select a;
```

You can use a more LINQ solution like this:

```
random = Enumerable.Range(0,30)
                   .Select(a=>(char)r.Next(97,123)).ToList();

//then assign the DataSource of your listBox1 instead of adding each item:
listBox1.Format += (s,e) => {
  e.Value = "Random Letters: " + e.Value;
};
listBox1.DataSource = random;

//in ascending order
var asc = random.OrderBy(a=>a);
```

Comment: Nice use of lovely Linq

Answer (score 1):

```
var asc = from a in random
orderby a ascending
select a;
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is because you need `List<char>` in your query for ordering, and you are passing it a single character `letters`.

```
var asc =
        from a in random//changehere
        orderby a ascending
        select a;
```

This does make a good case for using proper variable names. You can name your `letters` , `letter` since it is representing a single character.

**Also**, you are not adding random character to your list, instead you are just adding `i` after casting it to char. Change your code like:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        letters = (char)((int)'a' + r.Next(0, 26));
        random.Add(letters);
        listBox1.Items.Add("Random Letters:" + letters);
    }
```